# Replacing a imageIcon

Tags: java

I have a value called 'AmountWrongGuessed' that gives the amount of wrong guesses the users puts while guessing a word.
Each times the word is not found in the arraylist the AmountWrongGuessed goes ++.  (tested this wih a println and it works properly)

Now the problem is each time the AmountWrongGuessed goes 1 up it should display a ImageIcon.
*But insteed it displays the last image icon all the time, and skips the other icons.*

I use no layout mananger (its set to null, if this makes any difference in the total picture  setLayout = null)

Also while initialising this game the amountwrongguessed is default 0, yet it does not display the first imageicon either. (i used different labels before to add each icon on the same position but then i had the problem only the first image displayed and nothing changed).

```
public HrView(Hrgame hg) {
    this.hg = hg;

    CreateComponents();
    SetLayoutComponents();
    UpdateComponents();
    AddListeners();
}
```

Creation of the images:

```
 private void CreateComponents() {

    hang0 = new ImageIcon("hang0.gif");
    lblHang = new JLabel(hang0);
    lblHang.setLocation(60, -10);
    lblHang.setSize(200, 200);       

    hang1 = new ImageIcon("hang1.gif");
    lblHang = new JLabel(hang1);
    lblHang.setLocation(60, -10);
    lblHang.setSize(200, 200);

    hang2 = new ImageIcon("hang2.gif");
    lblHang = new JLabel(hang2);
    lblHang.setLocation(60, -10);
    lblHang.setSize(200, 200);
}

  private void AddListeners()
{
    btnCheck.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {

            hg.Input(tfToGuessInput.getText().toLowerCase());
            Pictures();
            lblHang.updateUI();

        }
    });
}


private void Pictures()
{
    //works, does increment
    System.out.println(hg.getAmountWrongGuessed());

    if (hg.getAmountWrongGuessed() == 0) {
        add(lblHang);
    }
    if (hg.getAmountWrongGuessed() == 1) {
        add(lblHang);
    }
    if (hg.getAmountWrongGuessed() == 2) {
        add(lblHang);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `CreateComponents()` your attribute `lblHang` references the label you created last (the one containing image `hang2`.) In order to use the 3 labels later on, you need to have 3 label attibutes which you can then use in `Pictures()`.

Btw, in Java the naming convention is that method names start with a lowercase character.

Comment: Now  have tried a Jlabel for each image by adding a new jlabel to the same position, but now i have no images that show up at all.

Comment: @Tonz, you can try using `setVisible()` to determine which icon shows, or alternatively use 1 label and use `setIcon()` to switch its image. In the latter case you don't need to construct 3 `JLabel` objects in `CreateComponents()`

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class testgui{

private static int flag = 1;

public static void main(String[] args){

final JLabel label = new JLabel("",new ImageIcon("0.jpg"),JLabel.CENTER);
final JLabel label1 = new JLabel("",new ImageIcon("1.jpg"),JLabel.CENTER);
final JLabel label2 = new JLabel("",new ImageIcon("2.jpg"),JLabel.CENTER);

final JFrame frame = new JFrame();

final JPanel panel = new JPanel();

frame.add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);

frame.setVisible(true);

final JButton button = new JButton("Next");

frame.add(button,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

panel.add(label);

frame.pack();

button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(flag==0){
        System.out.println("0.jpg");
        //label image, flag increment
            flag = flag+1;
            panel.removeAll();
            panel.add(label);
            frame.pack();

        } else if(flag==1){
        System.out.println("1.jpg");
        //label1 image, flag increment
            flag = flag+1;
            panel.removeAll();
            panel.add(label1);
            frame.pack();
        } else if (flag==2){
        System.out.println("2.jpg");
        //label2 image, reset flag to 0
            flag = 0;
            panel.removeAll();
            panel.add(label2);
            frame.pack();
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Wrong flag number !");
        }
        panel.validate();
        panel.updateUI();
        }
    });
}
    }
```

I think if you want to switch images, using jlabels, the above codes would help. It would help to rotate jlabels containing images but this codes are not optimized.

Comment: Is using labels actually the best solution for lets say rotating 7 images on the same spot? Pretty unclear what the best, most simple solution would be for this problem. Regards

Comment: You are right. Labels are not the best way to rotate images. You can have a Label without creating an instance. E.g. "JLabel label = null;" Then when you need a new image, you follow up with "label = new JLabel("",new ImageIcon("0.jpg"),JLabel.CENTER);". Make sure to update the filename of the image properly. You would only be using 1 label and it would simply keep cycling the images as you want.